# how to change the style of a txt file in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

In the past few days I have run into a problem, I have an iframe like this on my website:

```html
<iframe src ="http://hokuco.com/cde/user.txt" id ="myIframe"></iframe>
```

but, consolas looks so old and makes my website look like an 80s computer terminal. I have tried using font tags around the iframe and also I have tried changing the font type, is there any way I can just change the iframe text from consolas to arial?

Comment: Don't use an iframe, load the text file via AJAX call, insert it inside the document and then you can style the content with CSS like you would do with HTML.

Comment: how do you do that ps i dont know ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PHP:

**PHP**

```
<p><?php echo file_get_contents('http://hokuco.com/cde/user.txt'); ?></p>
```

---

Using JQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<p id="text"></p>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#text').load("http://hokuco.com/cde/user.txt");
```

Comment: just curious, us there any way you can use the jquery bit for say... a textarea?